# 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, flutter, uialertcontroller

```
    else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil)
                                    message:NSLocalizedString(@"Camera not available.", nil)
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        self.result(nil);
        self.result = nil;
        _arguments = nil;
      }

}
```

I am getting this error and I tried to change `'UIAlertView'` to `'UIAlertController'`still getting different errors.

Comment: Needless to say, use `UIAlertController`. And we obviously cannot comment on your attempt to use that without [seeing your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace in xCode build with below `UIAlertController`:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController 
alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Camera not available" 
preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style: style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];


[alert addAction:ok];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```